# How to run a bat file at specified day/time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduler

I have a bat file that I want to run at specific day/time in each quarter for a year.
I m new to command line and I know how to run it via a task scheduler, which is very easy.

Let's say for each quarter, for 1st and 2nd month, my bat file should run at alternative weeks. For the third month of a quarter, it should run weekly. Possible time would be early morning 6:00 a.m. How would I do it? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [windows scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task), but I doubt you are going to be able to do a schedule that advanced with just the windows scheduler.

What I would do is write the scheduling logic (e.g. when you want your batch file to run) in some high level language (C#, JAVA, etc.), then call that program at the beginning of your batch file to see if it's a date you care about.

The batch file could be set up to run each day (or multiple times per day if needed) using the windows scheduler, but it would only do the "real stuff" if your C#/JAVA program indicated that it was a date you cared about.

Comment: Thanks dcp for your i/p. If windows Scheduler is a better way to do it- schedule it that advanced, i will do it that way. I was just thinking of creating a vbs script that would call and run my bat file on specified date-time as mentioned in my question. That way, I won't have to schedule my bat file to run it multiple times via scheduler. Please let me know if that's doable.? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nemo - The bat file will still need to run at least once a day, and you can use the scheduler for that. If your script won't need to run at different times, you can just have it run the same time every day. You can probably code the date checking logic in vbs, as long as vbs has calendar objects, etc. where you can figure out if it's the first quarter, etc. But yes, I think it's doable.

Answer (score 3):

The Batch file below do what you want:

```
@echo off
rem Get the "monthInQuarter@weekInMonth" value of the last run:
set /P lastRun=< scheduler.txt
rem Get values from today date
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A "monthInQuarter=(1%%a-100)%%4, weekInMonth=(1%%b-101)/7+1, oddWeekInMonth=weekInMonth%%2"
)
if %weekInMonth% gtr 4 (
  set /A weekInMonth=4, oddWeekInMonth=0
)
set thisRun=%monthInQuarter%@%weekInMonth%
rem For 1st and 2nd month in each quarter:
if %monthInQuarter% leq 2 (
   rem For alternative weeks (1=yes, 2=no, 3=yes, 4=no):
   if %oddWeekInMonth% equ 1 (
      if "%thisRun%" neq "%lastRun%" (
         echo %thisRun%> scheduler.txt
         call :TheProcess
      )
   )
rem For the third month of a quarter:
) else if %monthInQuarter% equ 3 (
   rem Run it weekly:
   if "%thisRun%" neq "%lastRun%" (
      echo %thisRun%> scheduler.txt
      call :TheProcess
   )
)
exit

:TheProcess
rem Place here the desired process, ie:
echo This run only on selected weeks!
exit /B
```

This table of values may help to understand the scheduling logic:

```
month:          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
monthInQuarter: 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1  2  3  0

day:            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
weekInMonth:    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3 ...
oddWeekInMonth: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1 ...
```

Notes:

- This Batch file assume that ECHO %DATE% command show the date in MM/DD/YYYY format with a left zero if month or day is less than 10. If this is not your locale date format, a slight modification is needed.
- Although it is possible to modify this program to work with any date format, I think this is NOT a general-use file, but a very particular request for your specific needs.
- This program must run daily at 6:00 am via task scheduler.
- The first time the program run "The system cannot find the file specified." message appear, before auxiliary SCHEDULE.TXT file be created.

I hope it helps.

Antonio

PS - I don't think this problem can be solved in an easier way via vbs script or C#, JAVA, etc...

Comment: Thanks Aacini for your effort. I would love to understand your code. I have less experience in writing a batch file. Some additional comments to each line would help me better understand it. Just a thought. Thanks again. :) Your help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
  String hours=PropertyUtil.getProperty("START_HOURS");
 String minutes=PropertyUtil.getProperty("START_MINUTES");
  String hours1=PropertyUtil.getProperty("SECOND_START_HOURS");
     String minutes1=PropertyUtil.getProperty("SECOND_START_MINUTES");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(hours));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
     Long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
     System.out.println("Current time is : "+currentTime);
     //Check if current time is greater than our calendar's time. If So, then change date to one day plus. As the time already pass for execution.
     if (calendar.getTime().getTime() < currentTime) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }


    Date time = calendar.getTime(); 
    long  period = 1000L  60L  60L * 24L; // 24 Hours
    System.out.println(" First run  time is : "+time);
    System.out.println("milli seconds: "+period);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            
            try {
            System.out.println("  Service Started...."+new Date());
                //main logic
            System.out.println("service completed...."+new Date());
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }, time, period);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(hours1));
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes1));
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    //Check if current time is greater than our calendar's time. If So, then change date to one day plus. As the time already pass for execution.
    if (calendar1.getTime().getTime() < currentTime) {
        calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    Date time1 = calendar1.getTime();   
    System.out.println("Second run Time is : "+time1);
    System.out.println("Milli seconds : "+period);
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            
            try {
            System.out.println("  Service Started...."+new Date());
                //main logic
            System.out.println("service completed...."+new Date());
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }, time1, period);
                    

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).