# How to run a batch file on a schedule

Tags: batch-file, html

I want to make a batch file load fortnightly on a Friday at 9.00am. I would like to do it without task scheduler if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a bat file at specified day/time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019792/how-to-run-a-bat-file-at-specified-day-time)

Comment: You will have to run a batch file continuously for two weeks doing nothing but checking for 9am, every second friday.  If you explain the task then you might get another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows' built-in `at` command. [Documentation here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565).

Or the newer `schtasks` and using a RunInterval (`RI`) of 20160 minutes. [Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: He doesn't want to use task scheduler.